# Does speed of writing data on an optical disk affect the speed of reading data?

Tags: laser, speed, data

Does speed of writing data on an optical disk ( like DVD ) affect the speed of reading data from that disk ? even a little?

Comment: I think it is related to physics because of [this topic](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/32336/optical-drive-physics?rq=1) reading data from disk is related to light reflection and writing data on it is related to lasers and the substance used in the disk ,I want to know the role of speed of writing in the game , may higher speed make the laser to create worse pits and lands and why?

Comment: I think the main issue is how well and completely the laser writes its codewords. I think it is quite a good question as ideas of information theory are coming more and more into mainstream physics. However, beyond the information theoretic considerations, the question becomes quite "technological" - it depends on the physics of the exact writing process. If you can find out more about what this process is, perhaps you can ask another question about how one makes this writing process form unambiguous codes and how quickly it can do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only insofar that the maximum writing speed is limited by the need to unambiguously encode the disk's surface. If you tried to raise the speed of writing, the bit error rate increases: theoretically as a continuous, monotonic function of writing speed but practically a point is reached where the BER increases abruptly, so the BER as a function of speed tends to look like a step function. The writing data corresponds physically to changing the optical properties of the disk so this takes a nonzero time, and the more time one spends doing it, the more well formed the symbols are. As the BER increases, the error correction procedures, namely the computing of the nearest valid codeword to a corrupted one in coding space and, more importantly, repeat reads if error correction fails, use up more time, so the read gets markedly slower for a disk with a few errors, then fails altogether.

This phenomenon is very like the practical example where it gets harder and harder to read someone's hadnwriting as the writer gets more and more hurried and thus shapes their letters more and more ambiguously.